# Can Mathematica make the closed-path-integral sign?

Tags: formatting, input-forms

*Mathematica* seems to have the most complete library of mathematical typesetting characters anywhere outside of LaTeX, so I'm somewhat surprised that I can find no way to create the closed path integral symbol:

[image]

Can this really be, or have I just failed to discover it yet?

Comment: path integrals and contour integrals are not the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The symbol is `\[ContourIntegral]`.

Comment: Thanks! (And Yeesh… it's ugly. *sigh*)

Comment: You might be able to slant it a bit, by manually rotating it…

Comment: You can also try different fonts.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Patrick's answer, it might be helpful to point out that you can enter any LaTeX symbol by pressing `Esc`, typing the LaTeX code (including backslash) and then pressing `Esc` again. (So in this case `[Esc]\oint[Esc]`.)

Comment: That is *really* helpful to know! Thanks.